# How to redirect from old pages to new pages in php

Tags: php

I have many old pages like:

```
a.php, b.php,c.php... etc.
```

I want replace them with new pages:

```
x.php?q=a,  x.php?q=b,  x.php?q=c,  ... etc
```

So I replace code in a.php, b.php... as follows:

a.php new content:

```
<?php 
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
  header("location: x.php?q=a"); 
  exit(); 
?>
```

Is this correct? Thanks

Comment: No, it’s not correct, because per specification a `Location` header requires a full absolute URL.

Comment: Although per specification a Location header requires a full absolute URL, relative URL seems always work. Who can explain this?